# Exact ODE into an Inexact ODE

Tags: analysis, ordinary-differential-equations

It is something I just noticed while grading: Is it possible that an ODE is an Exact ODE in one form but after some algebraic manipulation it becomes an Inexact ODE?

Comment: I think so. Consider. $ye^xdy+\frac{y^2e^x}{2}dx=0$ So, $e^xdy+\frac{ye^x}{2}dx=0$  Often the differential equation became inexact due to annihilating of certain variable. That is why we can use method of integrating factor to make the differential equation exact! From inexact to exact!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Consider $$pdx + qdy = e^xy dx + e^x dy = 0$$ It is an exact ODE since $p_y = e^x = q_x$

Multiply by $xe^{-x}$. Then $$ xy dx + xdy = 0$$

Now, we test for exactness and find that $p_y = x \neq 1 = q_x$. Hence, inexact.